# DataType enum valid values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, data-annotations

I'm trying to find out what the valid options for EF DataAnnotations when applying the `[DataType(DataType.Something)]` attribute.  Looking through the MSDN docs I can only seem to find the valid ENUM values, but can't find any definitions for what qualifies for a given data type.

Specifically, I'm looking at the `DataType.PhoneNumber` I'm not sure that my current DB spec supports this since I can't find any input on what it's looking for if this is applied.

So my specific question is what are the acceptable values for a `DataType.PhoneNumber` with bonus points for a link that specifies the values for most/all of the different DataType enum values.

FOR CLARIFICATION...

When I say acceptable values I'm wondering are all three 5555555555, 555-555-5555, and (555) 555-5555 valid or only a subset?  Is there other acceptable values? Just not sure here. (Also, this will NEVER see anything international so my only concern is the US standard 10 digits.

Also, just to avoid some (I believe) unnecessary explanation...I'm aware that `DataType.Something` is an enum and doesn't hold the values itself...instead I'm wondering what the code that uses the enum considers valid.

[MSDN Ref for DataType enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in a point to test currently, but i would assume that the annotations declare regex patterns in the input fields they decorate, if you examine the output html you may find that the patter attribute is set, which should help you determine what can pass. An online regex tester will help you test what is possible.

I have used the [dataannotationsextentions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/)  nuget package. which extends the current available options also so if you find the current phonenumber annotation doesnt suit your means you should be able to create a custom validator which applies a regex which suits your conditions.

Cheers
Tim

Comment: At the moment all my validation is via unobtrusive.  While in a worst case scenario I could shut this off...I'd just assume find the info online.  However, +1 for pointing me towards that nuget package!